# Debugging with headless browser

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I have a `WebDriver` testsuite, which operates different when I execute it in normal and headless browser. There is an element which is not found when I execute it in headless mode, but found when I use the same code, same driver in normal mode.
I use this flag to set headless mode:

```
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
```

There is `ChromeDriver 2.31` and `WebDriver 3.5.2` in use. How could I debug this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways to debug. You can get Page Source and check what is different.

Now when you launch a browser using Selenium, it is using the Debugging session to automate chrome. So you can't do a remote debugger to your website using this.

You need to launch chrome manually.

```
chrome --headless --remote-debugging-port=9222 --disable-gpu http://tarunlalwani.com
```

Now in open another chrome and debug the site by going to `http://127.0.0.1:9222` and inspect the site.

[image: Debugging Session]

Comment: How is it possible, that headless browser couldn't find same xpath as normal browser?

Comment: Everything is possible. Even things not working as expected. So our only option is to find what works and use that.

Comment: Terminal, which OS do you have?

Comment: I use Windows 8.1.

Comment: I checked elements in normal mode and found all the elements, which I specified in test.

Comment: You will replace chrome in my command by `C:\ProgramData\....` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\....\Chrome.exe`...You need to see what path Chrome is installed on and updated the command that way and run it in Cmd

Comment: It is strange, because I get only a blank page, when I open page in this way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153596/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-plaidshirt).

Comment: Window size and responsive design

Answer (score 1):

for debugging headless, try to get an screenshot before the error:

in Python:

```
WINDOW_SIZE = "1200,900" opts.add_argument("--window-size=%s" % self.WINDOW_SIZE) 
if self.HEADLESS:   opts.add_argument('--headless')     
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver,options=opts)  


 driver.save_screenshot('./foto.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

for anyone struggling with this (as i was), there's a powerful method you can use in selenium called `execute_script`.

as an example, i was finding an element by xpath and clicking on it:

```py
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@id='tabletid']").click()
```

but this wasn't working in headless. after inspecting the element i found out the button click actually executes a simple javascript line. so i replaced this line with:

```py
js = """drawTable();
            return false;"""
    
browser.execute_script(js)
```

and i was able to actually pull my data! now my script will work in ssh, docker, etc.

Comment: Could you please explain it on an example site?

Comment: so like on this site my answer is `<div id="answer-64273543" class="answer" data-answerid="answer-64273543"...` if i parse thru it and find the button to "add comment" as `<button type="submit" class="s-btn s-btn_primary">...` i could select that element and `.click()` it in selenium. or if there were an equivalent javascript code that got ran when i clicked add comment i.e. `addComment(); return false;` i could use `.execute_script()` to run that instead, in case there are multiple elements or the driver can't find it