# Protractor times out when fetching resources in Chrome Headless

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, selenium, protractor

I am using Protractor to test an Angular app served locally. My OS is Windows 7 enterprise and I am using Chrome 61 with Protractor 5.1.

The `index.html` file loads a set of external resources (Bootstrap js/css etc), and trying to fetch these times out when running in Headless mode:

`https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css - Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

This does not happen when running Chrome normally.

My config for headless looks as such:

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    version: '',
    platform: 'ANY',
    specs: ['./features/**/*.feature'],
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=1600,1000']
    },
  },
```

Whereas the standard setup is:

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    version: '',
    platform: 'ANY',
    specs: ['./features/**/*.feature'],
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ['--no-sandbox', 'lang=en-US', '--disable-gpu'],
    },
  },
```

Comment: So headless not working and without headless same thing working?

Comment: Exactly, the tests run just fine in ordinary Chrome

Comment: Removing window-size and see if that changes anything

Comment: @TarunLalwani removed it, same issue.

Comment: Can you debug it through command line? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46017982/debugging-with-headless-browser/46018351#46018351

Comment: Was there any further development on this problem? I believe I'm seeing the same thing in C#.