# selenium tests fail against headless chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, headless

I am trying to get my selenium test automation to run against headless chrome so that I can move it to TeamCity. I have not had any luck. When I run it, Chrome does appear to run headlessly (no browser pops up), but I get a `NoSuchElementException`. The automation works as expected when run non-headlessly. A snapshot taken just shows a white rectangle.

I have researched this issue extensively, but I have not been able to find a solution that works for me. It appears that the issue was reported in  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=476, but it's marked fixed. I think the problem might be the wrong chromedriver, or maybe the wrong chromedriver/selenium combination, but I've tried all sorts of combinations and no love.

I am using:

- selenium-java 3.6.0
- chromedriver 2.33.506120
- Windows 7 Enterprise Service Pack1, 64-bit

My code is:

```
...
ChromeOptions headlessOptions = new ChromeOptions();
headlessOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
headlessOptions.addArguments("--headless");
driver = new ChromeDriver(headlessOptions);
driver.get(url);
WebElement usernameTextfield = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".input.username"));
...
```

And the output is:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f) on port 41402
Only local connections are allowed.
Nov 01, 2017 10:22:51 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".input.username"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=62.0.3202.75)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
```

This is preventing me from being able to include my test automation as part of our CI, so any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Try debugging the site in headless browser and see if the element is actually missing. See this thread for help on debugging https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46017982/debugging-with-headless-browser/46018351#46018351

Comment: "Chrome does appear to run headlessly (no browser pops up)" - what is your expectation of a headless browser?!?! What is `url`? Is it https, and is it using self-signed certificate?

Comment: @TarunLalwani, this was a great suggestion. Unfortunately, it confirmed what the screenshot was telling me - yes, the element is missing, because there's nothing there except a blank screen. Which leads me back to thinking there's a problem with how I'm using selenium/chromedriver/headless.

Comment: @SiKing My expectation of a headless browser is that it doesn't pop up on the monitor. I think that you may have mentally inserted "not" between "does" & "appear" in "Chrome does appear to run headlessly" :-) The URL is https, and it does use a self-signed certificate, but we have a setting on my test server that ignores checking the certificate.

Comment: Checking the cert is done by the browser, not the server. If you take a screenshot in your (failed) test, you will get only a blank page (as you have confirmed). Chrome-headless currently does **not** allow you to ignore bad certs. Chrome-GUI does. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=721739

Comment: And you are correct about the invisible "not". ;) Sorry, my bad.

Comment: @SiKing Thank you. I'm pretty sure that you nailed the issue. I'll talk with one of our devs.

Answer (score 10):

This is what worked for me:

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();                        
chromeOptions.AddArguments("--headless");
chromeOptions.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");
chromeOptions.AddArguments("--window-size=1280,800");
chromeOptions.AddArguments("--allow-insecure-localhost");

//specifically this line here :)
chromeOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("acceptInsecureCerts", true, true);
```

Found from https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=721739

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue, the local server was using selfsigned certificate, here is the combination that worked for me:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("--allow-insecure-localhost");
```

Comment: One more clarification, the ui server must run on the localhost where the selenium test runs, i.e. https://localhost:443

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
final ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("--window-size=1280,800");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: @Gustave, do you have a possible explanation as you why setting window-size changes the way test run happens? I have also noticed that when starting headless browser with chromeoption --start-maximized causes failure in headless mode. I am not sure what is the explanation for the same though.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the user-agent did the job for me:

```
--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who may stumble here with this error, but is utilizing python.

I was having issues with a script working only when headless was not utilized.

Initially, I had my options looking like this:

```
options = Options()
options.headless = True
```

After finding this thread, I altered my options to the following:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless");
options.add_argument("--window-size=1440, 900")
```

It appears that headless windows are formatted differently when selenium navigates the page. Go figure. This solved all of my issues.

Answer (score 1):

options.add_argument("--window-size=1440, 900")

after trying out what others recommended, this I taken from "Slyme" solved my issue. mine is a java framework.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your chromedriver/selenium combination looks perfect. Seems to me a puely synchronization issue. We need to induce some wait to syck up as follows:

```
driver.get(url);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement usernameTextfield = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".input.username"))));
usernameTextfield.sendKeys("user_name");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.

You need to add to your options your computer's user agent,
To search your user agent just type in google: ״`my user agent`״

Then add it to the options: `options.add_argument("your-user-agent")`

Comment: Getting this with use agent added: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.